# Magento1.7:Facing issue with shopping cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am facing some critical issue in Magento:
When I logged in and added some products in cart and logged out, again logged in then those products were still remaining in shopping cart.

----> This should not have happened because I set "Clear Persistence on Log Out".

The steps involved in this case are:

1. I logged in.
2. Added 2 products to my cart.
3. Now I logged out.
4. Then without logging in , I browsed the website and added 4 products to cart.
5. After that, at the time of checking out I was requested to login, so I logged in.
6. Now instead of 4 products(which is intended), I see 2+4=6 products in my cart during payment.

I configure as below --

- Enable Persistence -- Yes
- Persistence Lifetime (seconds) -- 60
- Enable "Remember Me" -- Yes
- "Remember Me" Default Value --- No
- Clear Persistence on Log Out -- Yes
- Persist Shopping Cart -- Yes

But unable to figure out the problem, in configuration I put 60 second. I logged out and after 5 minutes again I logged in. I found  products are remain in shopping cart.

According to configuration, product must be deleted from shopping cart after I logged out.

I messed up with this problem.
Kindly help me.

Comment: From my understanding this is basic Magento behaviour called a [Persistent Shopping Cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/)

Answer (score 0):

It's the persistent cart feature introduced in Magento 1.5. You can disable it at:

System->configuration->Persistent Shopping Cart

Comment: Hi,
I configure as below -- 

Enable Persistence -- Yes 
Persistence Lifetime (seconds) -- 60
Enable "Remember Me" -- Yes
"Remember Me" Default Value --- No 
Clear Persistence on Log Out -- Yes
Persist Shopping Cart -- Yes

But unable to figure out the problem, in configuration I put 60 second. I logged out and after 5 minutes again I logged in,I found  products are remain in shopping cart.

According to configuration,product must be deleted from shopping cart after I logged out.

I messed up with this problem.
Kindly help me.

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: It was introduced in Magento 1.6

Comment: I knew it was introduced in Magento1.6 . But question is how we disable this feature of magento ?