# Magento Persistent Shopping Cart not working, not clearing cart item?

Tags: php, magento

**Magento version: 1.9.0.1**

Issue: Persistent Shopping Cart is Enable Persistence **Yes** and Persistence Lifetime (seconds) is **60 second.** , but cart is not clearing even i wait more than 30 mins.

[image]

I see this question asked by someone 2 years ago in magento 1.7 but no answer.
[stack overflow question click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590926/magento1-7facing-issue-with-shopping-cart)

I have followed this link instruction but not working [Magento Persistent Shopping Cart settings](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-a-persistent-shopping-cart/)

**FYI:** I feel it may affect from extension, So tested with fresh installation of magento 1.9 version. but facing same issue.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Do you server have correctly set time/date and correctly set a cron job for magento?

Comment: Time/dates configured properly. Why cron job?

Comment: @HarikaranK From magento 1.9.0.1 all magento activities like sending order email , persistant cart and others are maintained using cron jobs so you have to set a cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento is important to run a root/cron.php script each 5 minutes. It is activating time dependent actions.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: Magento will not work correctly without cron. Many funcions depend on cron script. It is part of proper Magento installation.

Comment: are u sure your answer is anyway related to the question ?

Comment: Yes. Magento won't clear session cache in time interval, when nothing is running cron job.